# How to copy selected text from other website to a window opened from my website

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I am opening a new window that has a small form from my website. This is like a keyword submitting form.

People can search in different article website and submit keywords there.

I need a functionality where users can goto any website and hightlight the text they want to copy and this should be auto-filled in the keyword field in that window of my website

Is it something possible?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible if you like building browser plugins :)

[Firefox addons developer guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Firefox_addons_developer_guide)

[Google Chrome Extensions Developers Guide](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. This would be a time consuming job and we have to create add-ons for each browser. This is not what I am searching for.